# What Data ownership really is in EOS?

Tags: transactions, permissions, blockchains

All data of transactions can be view live as EOS is public , suppose i made a transaction on EOS block-chain this transaction belong to me but still people can see it.

Here is my Question how this data is own by me.
If the data really belong to me then no one could see it.

What i see ownership is that when you own something you have full control over it.
READ/WRITE/EXECUTE

But here you cannot write it as block-chain is immutable ,execute don't fit here and Read permission is global anyone can read it.

In reality i have nothing but to read same as other.

Answer (score 1):

> how this data is own by me. If the data really belong to me then no one could see it.

You sign the data (the transaction) with one or more private keys that you own. Everyone can see the transaction, everyone can verify that the transaction was made by you, but no regular user could've made that transaction without your secret key(s)--this is the ownership part.

Following your analogy, everyone has read access to your data, only you have write access to the data (you're the only one who can write and edit the transaction before signing it,) and BPs have execute permission to process your transaction and commit it on chain.

You're right that once processed in a block you can no longer edit the data.

Comment: what i will do if a want to make data private so no one could see without my permission

Comment: encrypt it before uploading on the chain (they'll still see the encrypted version) or don't put it on the chain